# how to convert data from array to json in zf2?

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, zend-framework2

i used mongo odm query for getting data but when i get query data it returns in array format but i want to get data in json format how i convert data from array to json?here is my code:

```
public function loadAction()
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
            $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
                $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
        $calendars = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Event')
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->field("calendar_id")->equals($id)
            ->getQuery()->execute();
        $array = array();
        if($calendars && !is_null($calendars) && is_object($calendars)){                    
            foreach($calendars as $key=>$value) {   
            $array[] = $value;
            }
        }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($array);
            echo "</pre>";
        return $response;
            //return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($array));
    }
```

and here is my response:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 11
        [calendar_id] => 44
        [title] => fhfhfhfhfhfhfhf
        [description] => hfhfhfhfhffh
        [begin] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1397744580
                [usec] => 0
            )

        [end] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1403187780
                [usec] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 12
        [calendar_id] => 44
        [title] => fhfhfhfhfhfhfhfdgdg
        [description] => hfhfhfhfhffhdgdgdg
        [begin] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1397744580
                [usec] => 0
            )

        [end] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1403360580
                [usec] => 0
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 13
        [calendar_id] => 44
        [title] => xvxvxvxv
        [description] => czzzvxvvzxvxvzxv
        [begin] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1398349380
                [usec] => 0
            )

        [end] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1403706180
                [usec] => 0
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 14
        [calendar_id] => 44
        [title] => xvxvxvxggjgjfj
        [description] => czzzvxvvzxhhdfhhd
        [begin] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1398349380
                [usec] => 0
            )

        [end] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1403706180
                [usec] => 0
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 15
        [calendar_id] => 44
        [title] => xvxvxvxggjgjfjsadgggggggfdhdfhhdh
        [description] => czzzvxvvzxhhdfhhddghhffffffffffffff
        [begin] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1398349380
                [usec] => 0
            )

        [end] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1404138180
                [usec] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

but i want dat in this format:

```
[{
    "event_id":"2",
    "calendar_id":"1",
    "author_id":"1",
    "title":"Launch",
    "description":"Launch Break",
    "begin":"2014-03-02 20:00:00",
    "end":"2014-03-31 16:53:00",
    "calendar_title":"Hijri Calender",
    "author_email":"arif.liaqat@yahoo.com"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($calendars && !is_null($calendars) && is_object($calendars)){                    
  foreach($calendars as $key => $value) {   
    $array[] = array(
        'event_id' => $value['_id'],
        'calendar_id' => $value['calendar_id'],
        'author_id' => $value['author_id'], // <-- author_id is defined?
        'title' => $value['title'],
        'description' => $value['description'],
        'begin' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value['begin']->sec),
        'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value['end']->sec),
        'calendar_title' => $value['calendar_title'], // <-- calendar_title is defined?
        'etc..' => $value['etc..'],
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use php native funcions **json_encode** and **json_decode** to get and put your variables in the specifc format

Answer (score 1):

Then you can return it via JsonModel (as mentioned JsonModel will encode the array!!):

```
return new JsonModel(array(
            'array' => $array
        ));
```

Don't forget to include JsonModel on top of your file:

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
```

Comment: so you have to do a json_encode before assigning the string to the JsonModel? wouldn't the JsonModel encode this automatically?

Comment: You are right, JsonModel will enocode it! I've edited my post.

Comment: I like this clean ZF2 way of doing things. However there doesn't seem much control over how escaping is done on the internal json_encode function of the ZF2 JsonModel object.